# Call devise resource object from some other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise

I have password updation in my application. I have to call the same form from some other controller. I had added the same form but its giving me the error undefined local variable or method `resource'. How can I call the update password from any other controller?
My form is this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: update_password_registrations_path(resource), html: { method: :put }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :current_password, required: true, wrapper: :prepend, error: true do %>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="ss-icon ss-key"></i></span>
    <%= f.input_field :current_password, placeholder: "Old Password" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true, wrapper: :prepend, error: true do %>
      <span class="add-on"><i class="ss-icon ss-key"></i></span>
      <%= f.input_field :password, placeholder: "New Password" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, wrapper: :prepend, error: true do %>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="ss-icon ss-key"></i></span>
        <%= f.input_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "New Password Confirmation" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think the resource object's scope is not beyond devise views or controllers or models.

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: Have updated the code for the form above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource is whatever you called your devise resource. So it's probably user.

Replace

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: update_password_registrations_path(resource), html: { method: :put }, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: update_password_registrations_path(@user), html: { method: :put }, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Make sure you set `@user` in your controller. If it is a form for the current user you can replace `@user` with `current_user`.